# What is g++'s -pthread equiv in clang?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, g++, pthreads, clang

I'm switching over from g++ to clang

however, in g++, I have the -pthread flag, which clang does not seem to recognize.

What is the equiv in clang?

EDIT: My clang build is pulling from svn on March 5 2010.

Comment: the link i posted, suggests that clang indeed accepts -pthread. Check if something else is wrong. What error message did you get?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Clang [supports](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-pthread) `-pthread`. May be in the latest builds, so update it and try again.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

Answer (score 35):

clang requires `-pthread` when compiling but not when linking. This is annoying, but it is observed behavior:

```
$ clang -c x.cpp
$ clang -pthread -c x.cpp
$ clang -o x x.o
$ clang -pthread -o x x.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
$ 

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
$
```