# What kind of structure of C that place parenthesises before function call?

Tags: c

I came across this line of code today in process and thread chapter of C programming book:

```
printf("[Child]  child thread id: 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
```

I've never seen the part `(unsigned int)pthread_self()`, I don't know what the first pair of parenthesises is used for. Any idea?

p.s:

I remember that in the documentation of php, there's similar expression for function documentation:

`int time()`

but in actual code, we only use the part `time()`, int is for documentation purpose to show the return value of function `time()`

---

**Update:**

I type the example code in the book that test the each thread id:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int global = 5;

void* ChildCode(void* arg) {
    int local = 10;

    global++;
    local++; 
    printf("[Child]  child thread id: 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
    printf("[Child]  global: %d  local: %d\n", global, local);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t  childPid;
  int       local = 10;

    printf("[At start]  global: %d  local: %d\n", global, local);

  /* create a child thread */
  if (pthread_create (&childPid, NULL, ChildCode, NULL) != 0)
  {
    perror("create");
    exit(1);
  } else { /* parent code */
    global++;
    local--; 
    printf("[Parent] parent main thread id : 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
    printf("[Parent] global: %d  local: %d\n", global, local);
    sleep(1);
  }
  printf("[At end] global: %d  local: %d\n", global, local);
  exit(0);
}
```

and it gives me some note(not warning not error):

```
clang example_thread.c 
/tmp/example_thread-9lEP70.o: In function `main':
example_thread.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've no idea with the code, any idea?

Comment: You need to pass `-pthread` to clang.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391194/what-is-gs-pthread-equiv-in-clang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are casting the return value of `pthread_self` to `unsigned int`.  `pthread_self` returns `pthread_t`, which is an unspecified arithmetic type that is not appropriate for use with `printf`.

Comment: `pthread_t` need not be an arithmetic type or even a scalar type, e.g. it could be a huge structure. This would be really inefficient, but it's allowed, and thus code containing this cast is invalid. The only way to portably print `pthread_t` is to print its representation as `unsigned char[sizeof(pthread_t)]`.

Comment: And if you are going to assume `pthread_t` is a scalar type, you should still use `uintmax_t`, not `unsigned int`. The latter is too short to represent all values of `pthread_t` on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `pthread_self()` is a `pthread_t` (see [`man pthread_self`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_self)).

`(unsigned int) pthread_self()` is used to cast the return value of `pthread_self()` into an unsigned integer.

For more information about casting in C see http://www.aui.ma/personal/~O.Iraqi/csc1401/casting.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer, totally make sense to me, and also for great reference

Answer (score 1):

This is just casting of the return value of the function to `unsigned int`.

It is just like:

```
pthread_t pthread_self_result;
pthread_self_result = pthread_self();
printf("[Child]  child thread id: 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self_result);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, and your example code, so the casting the value is for printf use, isn't it?

Comment: Could you help me to check the error message which I update for the question, the code won't compile

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called in C a "type cast"
Here we cast the pthread_t type into an unsigned int to print it.
Please refer to your C language manual

Comment: +1 for pointing out the term "type cast". And sorry for this noobie question, I should thoroughly learn the C reference, but it's not easy for a noob like me, but I'm trying