# OS X clang -pthread

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

What are the compiler/linker requirements for using pthread library with clang in OS X.

With GCC i know that using -pthread set the appropriate compiler/linker options, but i unsure about OS X with clang.

```
air:~ jose$ clang++ -c test.cpp -pthread
air:~ jose$ clang++ -o test -pthread test.o 
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'

air:~ jose$ g++ -c test.cpp -pthread
air:~ jose$ g++ -o test -pthread test.o
```

Comment: Should be exactly the same - I'm pretty sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391194/what-is-gs-pthread-equiv-in-clang

Comment: see the sample i just added, seems that clang doesn't need -pthread when linking the executable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

clang requires `-pthread` when compiling but not when linking. This is annoying, but it is observed behavior:

```
$ clang -c x.cpp
$ clang -pthread -c x.cpp
$ clang -o x x.o
$ clang -pthread -o x x.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
$ 

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
$
```

Comment: Does compiling and linking simultaneously emit a warning with/without `-pthread`?  (`clang -o x x.cpp`, I think)  That's the one combination you don't try in your answer. (I don't have easy access to a Mac, but am trying to develop for one...)